# Why did one character vanish but not the other one?

Tags: star-wars, the-rise-of-skywalker

At the climax of *Star Wars: The Rise Of Skywalker*

> Rey

dies while killing the bad guy,

> Palpatine.

Then

> Ben Solo,

comes and uses Force Life Transfer++ to save her life. But in the process, he dies and *vanishes*. **So why did he vanish upon his death but she didn't vanish upon hers?**

Comment: It's like when coyote runs off a cliff and stands there in the air for a second before gravity notices him.

Comment: Because she wasn't dead dead. Just a bit dead.

Comment: @Valorum - She was only mostly dead, which is still a little bit alive.  If she'd been dead-dead, Ben would have gone through her pockets for loose change.

Comment: Because Leia picked up him by the scruff of the neck for a joint teleport into Force Ghost land obviously.

Comment: This is the kind of thing that is honestly killing these movies.

Comment: Well, Rey is Mary Sue of Mary Sue's , and Kylo Ren/Ben Solo is trying to get woke and get rid of his toxic masculinity :) In the process he must die to atone for his sins :P

Comment: Out of universe: to prevent questions about why she didn’t then resurrect him, etc., in an infinite hilarious chain.

Answer (score 13):

Rey was still clinging very faintly to life, not enough to allow a med team to heal her, but enough that a transference of Force could revive her.

Ben was badly injured but expended the last of his life force giving it to Rey, in fact the final transference probably happened during the kiss. Therefore there was no spark of life remaining in Ben to allow him to be revived at all.

Comment: As anyone who has ever worked rescue operations can tell you, 'death' is a spectrum.

Comment: @Jeff they were only "mostly dead".  Only Rey's love of bluffing is keeping her alive

Comment: I think Rey was "dead-dead" and Kylo Ren used the Dark Side of the force to resurrect her; turning back to evil at the end by necessity to save Rey's life. He than *translocated/teleported* himself away (his ability to translocate using the force proven by his ability to grab Rey's necklace earlier in the film, the first such use of the force for that, I believe). This sets up the next 9 or so movies...

Comment: @JimmyFix-it any source for Ben not dying at the end? I don't remember any times they just faded away after being connected by the force or completely teleported when physically in the same location. They've been able to interact physically through the force but not be completely present from my understanding

Comment: @GammaGames, no source, just thinking through his change (Dark-to-Light) and how it fits (or doesn't). Anakin did not repent till much later in life. I don't remember previous distant *physical* interaction through the force, and I am concluding that Ren has taken an evolutionary "Force Step". Mostly my proposal is to be arbitrary, lol.

Comment: @JimmyFix-it I don't think there was any physical interactions before this movie, and to my limited knowledge TLJ was the first time they showed anyone interacting face-to-face with the force over long distances.
I took it as both Ben and Leia ghosting at the same time, though it was a bit odd.